# How to find label value (database coloumn) of repeater and change text on repeater_ItemDataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my database value "2012/04/24" i dispalyed in label of repeater
    i have to display database value like this 12-Apr-2012 in label of repeater. 
    on repeater_ItemDataBound event How can i do it.

```
<td class="csstablelisttd">
   <asp:Label ID="lblPatientsBirthDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Patients_Birth_Date")%>'></asp:Label>td>  
  protected void repeaterPatientList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        Label lblbirthDate = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPatientsBirthDate");


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void repeaterPatientList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        Label lblbirthDate = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPatientsBirthDate");
        if(lblbirthDate!= null)
        {
           DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(lblbirthDate.Text);
           lblbirthDate.Text = d.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        }
    }
```

If date conversion cause error then follow [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx#Y1596)  and the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For formatting date into a particular format, it could be done by this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPatientsBirthDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Patients_Birth_Date", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%>' </asp:Label>
```

You need to change text on repeater_ItemDataBound event.

Hope this will help you.